# Are "benaphores" worth implementing on modern OS's?

Tags: multithreading, mutex, atomic, semaphore

Back in my days as a BeOS programmer, I read [this article](http://www.haiku-os.org/legacy-docs/benewsletter/Issue1-26.html#Engineering1-26) by Benoit Schillings, describing how to create a "benaphore":  a method of using atomic variable to enforce a critical section that avoids the need acquire/release a mutex in the common (no-contention) case.

I thought that was rather clever, and it seems like you could do the same trick on any platform that supports atomic-increment/decrement.

On the other hand, this looks like something that could just as easily be included in the standard mutex implementation itself... in which case implementing this logic in my program would be redundant and wouldn't provide any benefit.

Does anyone know if modern locking APIs (e.g. pthread_mutex_lock()/pthread_mutex_unlock()) use this trick internally?  And if not, why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your article describes is in common use today.  Most often it's called "[Critical Section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682530(VS.85).aspx)", and it consists of an interlocked variable, a bunch of flags and an internal synchronization object (Mutex, if I remember correctly).  Generally, in the scenarios with little contention, the Critical Section executes entirely in user mode, without involving the kernel synchronization object.  This guarantees fast execution.  When the contention is high, the kernel object is used for waiting, which releases the time slice conductive for faster turnaround.

Generally, there is very little sense in implementing synchronization primitives in this day and age.  Operating systems come with a big variety of such objects, and they are optimized and tested in significantly wider range of scenarios than a single programmer can imagine.  It literally takes years to invent, implement and test a good synchronization mechanism.  That's not to say that there is no value in trying :)

Comment: Let me be specific for a moment. On Linux the modern (NPTL) threading library relies internally on futexes, which are exactly this trick, keeping the uncontended case in userspace, leaving the kernel to handle the contended cases.

To quote the manual page "Implementors are expected to be assembly literate and to have read the sources of the futex userspace library". This stuff is really hard and really unforgiving of mistakes. So you should not re-invent the wheel unless you have a really compelling reason.

Answer (score 0):

Java's [`AbstractQueuedSynchronizer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.html) (and its sibling [`AbstractQueuedLongSynchronizer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedLongSynchronizer.html)) works similarly, or at least it *could* be implemented similarly. These types form the basis for several concurrency primitives in the Java library, such as [`ReentrantLock`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) and [`FutureTask`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html).

It works by way of using an atomic integer to represent state. A lock may define the value 0 as unlocked, and 1 as locked. Any thread wishing to acquire the lock attempts to change the lock state from 0 to 1 via an atomic *compare-and-set* operation; if the attempt fails, the current state is not 0, which means that the lock is owned by some other thread.

`AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` also facilitates waiting on locks and notification of *conditions* by maintaining *CLH queues*, which are lock-free linked lists representing the line of threads waiting either to acquire the lock or to receive notification via a condition. Such notification moves one or all of the threads waiting on the condition to the head of the queue of those waiting to acquire the related lock.

*Most* of this machinery can be implemented in terms of an atomic integer representing the state as well as a couple of atomic pointers for each waiting queue. The actual scheduling of which threads will contend to inspect and change the state variable (via, say, [`AbstractQueuedSynchronizer#tryAcquire(int)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.html#tryAcquire%28int%29)) is outside the scope of such a library and falls to the host system's scheduler.