# Optimal strategy to make a C++ hash table, thread safe

Tags: c++, thread-safety, hashtable

(I am interested in design of implementation NOT a readymade construct that will do it all.)

Suppose we have a class HashTable (not hash-map implemented as a tree but hash-table)
and say there are eight threads.
Suppose  read to write ratio is about 100:1 or even better 1000:1.
Case A)  Only one thread is a writer and others including writer can read from HashTable(they may simply iterate over entire hash table)
Case B)  All threads are identical and all could read/write.

Can someone suggest best strategy to make the class thread safe with following consideration
1. Top priority to least lock contention
2. Second priority to least number of locks

My understanding so far is thus : 
One BIG reader-writer lock(semaphore).
Specialize the semaphore so that there could be eight instances writer-resource for case B, where each  each writer resource locks one row(or range for that matter).
(so i guess 1+8 mutexes)

Please let me know if I am thinking on the correct line, and how could we improve on this solution.

Comment: A hash-map is never implemented as a tree. A std::map *is* implemented as a tree, but it's name doesn't include the word "hash" anywhere.

Comment: @Ken, I know, I just wanted to make clear that I am talking about Table and not about Tree, as they will have pretty different characteristics for lock-free/minimal lock implementation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With such high read/write ratios, you should consider a lock free solution, e.g. [nbds](http://code.google.com/p/nbds/).

EDIT:

In general, lock free algorithms work as follows:

- arrange your data structures such that for each function you intend to support there is a point at which you are able to, in one atomic operation, determine whether its results are valid (i.e. other threads have not mutated its inputs since they have been read) and commit to them; with no changes to state visible to other threads unless you commit. This will involve leveraging platform-specific functions such as Win32's atomic compare-and-swap or Cell's cache line reservation opcodes.
- each supported function becomes a loop that repeatedly reads the inputs and attempts to perform the work, until the commit succeeds.

In cases of very low contention, this is a performance win over locking algorithms since functions mostly succeed the first time through without incurring the overhead of acquiring a lock. As contention increases, the gains become more dubious.

Typically the amount of data it is possible to atomically manipulate is small - 32 or 64 bits is common - so for functions involving many reads and writes, the resulting algorithms become complex and potentially very difficult to reason about. For this reason, it is preferable to look for and adopt a mature, well-tested and well-understood third party lock free solution for your problem in preference to rolling your own.

Hashtable implementation details will depend on various aspects of the hash and table design. Do we expect to be able to grow the table? If so, we need a way to copy bulk data from the old table into the new safely. Do we expect hash collisions? If so, we need some way of walking colliding data. How do we make sure another thread doesn't delete a key/value pair between a lookup returning it and the caller making use of it? Some form of reference counting, perhaps? - but who owns the reference? - or simply copying the value on lookup? - but what if values are large?

Lock-free stacks are well understood and relatively straightforward to implement *(to remove an item from the stack, get the current top, attempt to replace it with its next pointer until you succeed, return it; to add an item, get the current top and set it as the item's next pointer, until you succeed in writing a pointer to the item as the new top; on architectures with reserve/conditional write semantics, this is enough, on architectures only supporting CAS you need to append a nonce or version number to the atomically manipulated data to avoid the [ABA problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem))*. They are one way of keeping track of free space for keys/data in an atomic lock free manner, allowing you to reduce a key/value pair - the data actually stored in a hashtable entry - to a pointer/offset or two, a small enough amount to be manipulated using your architecture's atomic instructions. There are others.

Reads then become a case of looking up the entry, checking the kvp against the requested key, doing whatever it takes to make sure the value will remain valid when we return it (taking a copy / increasing its reference count), checking the entry hasn't been modified since we began the read, returning the value if so, undoing any reference count changes and repeating the read if not.
Writes will depend on what we're doing about collisions; in the trivial case, they are simply a case of finding the correct empty slot and writing the new kvp.
The above is greatly simplified and insufficient to produce your own safe implementation, especially if you are not familiar with lock-free/wait-free techniques. Possible complications include the ABA problem, priority inversion, starvation of particular threads; I have not addressed hash collisions.

The nbds page links to an [excellent presentation](http://www.azulsystems.com/events/javaone_2008/2008_CodingNonBlock.pdf) on a real world approach that allows growth / collisions. Others exist, a quick Google finds lots of papers.

Lock free and wait free algorithms are fascinating areas of research; I encourage the reader to Google around. That said, naive lock free implementations can easily look reasonable and behave correctly much of the time while in reality being subtly unsafe. While it is important to have a solid grasp on the principles, I strongly recommend using an existing, well-understood and proven implementation over rolling your own.

Comment: I feel like, with lock-free algos, I have been introduced to a parallel universe where lock never existed. Darn, now will have read all of them now. :)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at Java's [ConcurrentHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) implementation for one possible implementation.

The basic idea is **NOT** to lock for every read operation but only for writes. Since in your interview they specifically mentioned an extremely high read:write ratio it makes sense trying to stuff as much overhead as possible into writes.

The ConcurrentHashMap divides the hashtable into so called "Segments" that are themselves concurrently readable hashtables and keep every single segment in a consistent state to allow traversing without locking.

When reading you basically have the usual hashmap get() with the difference that you have to worry about reading stale values, so things like the value of the correct node, the first node of the segment table and next pointers have to be volatile (with c++'s non-existent memory model you probably can't do this portably; c++0x should help here, but haven't looked at it so far).

When putting a new element in there you get all the overhead, first of all having to lock the given segment. After locking it's basically a usual put() operation, but you have to guarantee atomic writes when updating the next pointer of a node (pointing to the newly created node whose next pointer has to be already correctly pointing to the old next node) or overwriting the value of a node.

When growing the segment, you have to rehash the existing nodes and put them into the new, larger table. The important part is to clone nodes for the new table as not to influence the old table (by changing their next pointers too early) until the new table is complete and replaces the old one (they use some clever trick there that means they only have to clone about 1/6 of the nodes - nice that but I'm not really sure how they reach that number). 
Note that garbage collection makes this a whole lot easier because you don't have to worry about the old nodes that weren't reused - as soon as all readers are finished they will automatically be GCed. That's solvable though, but I'm not sure what the best approach would be.

I hope the basic idea is somewhat clear - obviously there are several points that aren't trivially ported to c++, but it should give you a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

No need to lock the whole table, just have a lock per bucket. That immediately gives parallelism. Inserting a new node to the table requires a lock on the bucket about to have the head node modified. New nodes are always added at the head of the table so that readers can iterate through the nodes without worrying about seeing new nodes.

Each node has a r/w lock; readers iterating get a read lock lock. Node modification requires a write lock.

Iteration without the bucket lock leading to node removal requires an attempt to take the bucket lock, and if it fails it must release the locks and retry to avoid deadlock because the lock order is different.

Brief overview.

Comment: 1. Wouldn't it mean , if someone wants to read from HT, then he will have to check all locks ?
2. Also it would mean n locks, for n HT rows/buckets. That would be unacceptable. (Or maybe you meant have 8 locks, one for each thread which could lock one row ? )

Comment: What happens if a thread removes an item from the table while another thread is reading the table -- since the reader does not acquire any lock the node its currently looking at in a bucket might go away...

Comment: To lookup by key: 1. Hash the key to get the bucket number. 2. Lock the bucket. 3. Find the node in the bucket chain. 4. Lock the node. 5. Release the bucket lock.

Comment: @Chris Dodd: Removing a node is only an issue in terms of readers in the same bucket. "Readers iterating get a read lock", which is incompatible with the write lock on the node.

Comment: @janm : Correct me if I am wrong. Locks are really expensive. they (as I understand) are kernel objects. how  can we have 1 lock per bucket and 1 lock per node ?

Comment: Locks aren't as expensive as they used to be:  See Rom's answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635416/are-benaphores-worth-implementing-on-modern-oss

Comment: @Ajeet: An important strategy to making things concurrent is removing contention on locks. You can do by having locks represent smaller parts of the structure. This implies more locks, but less contention per lock. Why is that unacceptable, especially when your highest priority is "least lock contention?" Unclear how you expect one lock per thread to work.

Comment: @Ajeet: You need cheap locks. For the nodes, you want to think more "latches"  or "spin locks" rather than operating system level mutexes. These are short locks and you need to be careful with concurrency, but that is the nature of your question.

Comment: If you have a lock per bucket but not one for the table, how do you safely grow the table?

Comment: @Jeremy Friesner While Critical Sections are extremely cheap that's a Windows only solution. And as I understand it normal locks on Linux are much more expensive. Though the comment of your linked answer mentions a specific library so I assume that should take care of that. Still we can do without readlocks - see my post ;)

Comment: @moonshadow: If you are going to rebalance the buckets, you are rehashing every key and need to restrict operations on the table. You can allow operations on the individual nodes to continue, but you cannot iterate, insert or delete nodes. Yes, you need a higher level lock to deal with that issue.

Comment: @Voo AFAIK Linux (i.e. pthreads) can and does implement all the clever optimizations that Windows does (and possibly some other ones).  It's not like Microsoft's thread libraries are the only ones allowed to use clever optimizing tricks :^)

Answer (score -1):

You can try atomic_hashtable for c
https://github.com/Taymindis/atomic_hashtable for read, write, and delete without locking while multithreading accessing the data, Simple and Stable

API documents given in README.

Comment: Read the first line of the question.